# Guice: How can I cache data

Tags: java, web-applications, guice

I am new to `Guice` and have a question regarding caching.

I have a WebApp which uses a provider to provide user configurations.

```
bind(UserConfiguration.class).toProvider(UserConfigurationProvider.class).in(ServletScopes.REQUEST);
```

The provider is declared as:

```
public class UserConfigurationProvider implements Provider<UserConfiguration>{
    public UserConfiguration get() {
        userConfigurationDatabase.getUserConfiguration(<some param here>);
    }
}
```

In the get method, it calls `DB` and make a very expensive `DB` call.

I have a number of classes which get `UserConfiguration` injected like:

```
public class PriceView {
    private UserConfiguration userConfiguration;
    @Inject
    public MyClass(UserConguration userConfiguration){
        this.userConfiguration = userConfiguration;
    }

    .....
}

public class OrderView {
    private UserConfiguration userConfiguration;
    @Inject
    public MyClass(UserConguration userConfiguration){
        this.userConfiguration = userConfiguration;
    }
   ........
}
```

The problem is that every time I switch a view, a new xxxxView object is created and hence a new `UserConfiguration` is injected and hence the expensive `DB` call is called.

I want to make calling the `DB` limited to once per user login. My idea is that cache the `UserConfiguration` somewhere when a user login and clear it after user logout or it expires.

But I want to know whehter `Guice` offers something more clever ways of caching about this use case?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using standard servlet session, then it should be enough to use `ServletScopes.SESSION` scope instead of `ServletScopes.REQUEST`. In this case the injected object should be created only once per session.

However, if you are not using standard servlet session but something custom, then you also need to create [custom scope](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomScopes).